# How do I regex split by space, avoiding spaces within apostrophes?

Tags: regex, split

I want `"git log --format='(%h) %s' --abbrev=7 HEAD"` to be split into

```
[
  "git", 
  "log",
  "--format='(%h) %s'",
  "--abbrev=7",
  "HEAD"
]
```

How to I achieve this, without splitting on the space within `--format='(%h) %s'`?

Answers in any language is welcome :)

Comment: Regex is the wrong decision for this task.

Comment: @Jan, how did I miss that? You are no doubt correct, but it still should have been stated. I'm putting my comment here as I will delete my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No worries, I might as well be incorrect. It's just one input string so it might not be a general rule.

Comment: @PeterRader: No, it's not. At least not in general.

Comment: @Jan In this case regex forces the Format to not contain characters like a '

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found one possible (albeit ugly) solution in python (which also works with `"`):

```
>>> import re
>>> foo = '''git log --format='(%h) %s' --foo="a b" --bar='c d' HEAD'''
>>> re.findall(r'''(\S*'[^']+'\S*|\S*"[^"]+"\S*|\S+)''', foo)
['git', 'log', "--format='(%h) %s'", '--foo="a b"', "--bar='c d'", 'HEAD']
```

Answer (score 2):

As often in life, you have choices.

---

1. Use an expression that matches and captures different parts. This can be combined with a replacement function as in

   ```
   import re
   string = "git log --format='(%h) %s' --abbrev=7 HEAD"

   rx = re.compile(r"'[^']*'|(\s+)")

   def replacer(match):
       if match.group(1):
           return "#@#"
       else:
           return match.group(0)

   string = rx.sub(replacer, string)
   parts = re.split('#@#', string)
   #                 ^^^ same as in the function replacer
   ```
2. You could use the better [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

   ```
   import regex as re
   string = "git log --format='(%h) %s' --abbrev=7 HEAD"

   rx = re.compile(r"'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+")
   parts = rx.split(string)
   ```
3. Write yourself a little parser:

   ```
   def little_parser(string):
       quote = False
       stack = ''

       for char in string:
           if char == "'":
               stack += char
               quote = not quote
           elif (char == ' ' and not quote):
               yield stack
               stack = ''
           else:
               stack += char

       if stack:
           yield stack

   for part in little_parser(your_string):
       print(part)
   ```

---

All three will yield

```
['git', 'log', "--format='(%h) %s'", '--abbrev=7', 'HEAD']
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the idea is to split the string on contiguous spaces except where the spaces are part of a substring surrounded by single quotes. I believe this will work:

```
/(?:[^ ']*(?:'[^']+')?[^ ']*)*/
```

but invite readers to subject it to careful scrutiny.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Lqtpp/6/)

This regex can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
  [^ ']*    # match 0+ chars other than spaces and single quotes
  (?:       # begin non-capture group
    '[^']+' # match 1+ chars other than single quotes, surrounded
            # by single quotes 
  )?        # end non-capture group and make it optional
  [^ ']*    # match 0+ chars other than spaces and single quotes
)*          # end non-capture group and execute it 0+ times
/x          # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

This obviously will not work if there are nested single quotes.

@n.'pronouns'm. suggested an alternative regex that also works:

```
/([^ "']|'[^'"]*')*/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Lqtpp/7/)

Comment: I think the idea is that substrings in single quotes may appear any number of times including zero.  So you need something like `"([^ "']|'[^'"]*')*"`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., thanks for the catch. I revised my answer.